# caching this mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, caching

i have this table:

```
+----+-------+-----+-------+
| id | clave | lan | texto |
+====+=======+=====+=======+
|  1 | hi    | 1   | Hello |
|  3 | hi    | 2   | Hola  |
```

with this method

```
function get_texto_clave($clave){
    /* Checks the session language, finds and returns texto for the given clave*/

    $clave = htmlspecialchars($clave);
    $lan = detectarIdioma();
    $temporal = new texto($clave, $lan);
    if($temporal->exists()==true){
        return $temporal->get_texto();
    }else{
        return $clave;
    }
}
```

USAGE:

let say we want to print a form:

```
<form>
    <?php echo get_texto_clave('form_enter_login'); ?>
    <input type="text" />
    <?php echo get_texto_clave('form_enter_password'); ?>
    <input type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo get_texto_clave('form_enter_login'); ?>" />
</form>
```

As you can see, for this simple form we already performed 3 querys....

question is: how can i cache this results? do you suggest another implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on (clave, lan), I would not worry too much. MySQL will almost certainly take the table in memory. The alternative, having `$t[lan][clave]` not necessarily is better.
But you always have the option to generate with SQL a php source defining that array.

Alternatively you might consider Gettext for internationalization, using a .po file per language.